# Probability of choosing at least one box with an extra cookie when selecting $12$ boxes from $50$ boxes, of which $10$ have extra cookies?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Question from my discrete math homework...

> Some sneaky girl scouts are selling $50$ boxes of cookies (all the same kind of cookies) and they’ve added a cookie to each of $10$ boxes. If you buy $12$ boxes (without seeing how many cookies are inside), what is the probability that you will end up with at least one box with an extra cookie?

I'm not very sure where to start here. Would I use $k$-combinations and if so how?

> The answer is 445433837/466921735.

*Thanks for the help in advance!*

Comment: how many combinations of 12 boxes are there ? that should start you off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

calculate the probability of *not* getting any one of those boxes and subtract that from $1$

How many ways are there to get 12 boxes out of 50? A: ${50}\choose{12}$

How many ways are there to get 12 boxes out of the 40 non-extra boxes? A: ${40}\choose{12}$

So, the probability of *not* getting one of the special boxes is:

$$\frac{{40}\choose{12}}{{50}\choose{12}}$$

Subtract that from $1$ and you have your answer.

Comment: Only ten boxes have extra cookies.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Whoops! Thanks!

Comment: wow, that's quite easy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JimmyNeutron You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure about how much you know about probability. Here are the first two steps you should take when you read similar questions:

1. The first thing I notice is I am taking a sample of $n$ elements from a population of $N$ elements.
2. The second thing I note is that there are two elements: boxes with an extra cookie, and boxes without an extra cookie.

This is a classic hypergeometric probability distribution. The formula for a hypergeometric distribution is as follows:

[image: hypergeometric formula]

I would take the complement of this situation which is $1-P(\text{choosing no boxes with extra cookies})$

Using the formula for the hypergeometric distribution, we have:

1. X: the number of boxes without an extra cookie so we want $P(X=12)$
2. a: the elements that satisfy X which are the number of boxes without extra cookies so a = 40
3. r: is the sample size so r = 12
4. n  is the population size so n = 50

Now you just need to plug those numbers in and compute the probability and then subtract your answer from one. It checks out with me. Let me know if you are unsure about probability distributions and random variables.

Answer (score 0):

We need to buy at least one box with an extra cookie. The probability of buying $k$ boxes with an extra cookie is $\dfrac{\binom{10}{k}\binom{40}{12-k}}{\binom{50}{12}}.$ Since $1\le k\le 12$ we have that the asked probability is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{12}\dfrac{\binom{10}{k}\binom{40}{12-k}}{\binom{50}{12}}=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{12}\binom{10}{k}\binom{40}{12-k}}{\binom{50}{12}}=\dfrac{\binom{50}{12}-\binom{40}{12}}{\binom{50}{12}},$$ where in the last equality we have used the Vandermonde's identity (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)).

(Obviously the answer by @Bram28 gives a quicker way to get the asked probability.)